# If $b$ is the geometric mean of $a$ and $c$, then $b^2$ is the geometric mean of $a^2$ and $c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone tell me if I proved this correctly? I'm new to proofs.

\begin{align}
b^2 &= ac \\
\sqrt{b^2} &= \sqrt{ac} \\
b &= \pm \sqrt{ac} \\
b^4 &= (\sqrt{ac})^4 \\
b^4 &= a^2 c^2 \\
\sqrt[4]{b^4} &= \sqrt[4]{a^2c^2} \\
b &= \pm \sqrt{ac}
\end{align}

Comment: After two years on this site, knowing how to write should be mandatory.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting your question this time, but I strongly encourage you to learn at least the basics of LaTeX/MathJax.

Comment: Also, as written this seems to prove the converse.

Comment: Thanks for editing that mess.

Comment: I rolled back some changes which eliminated line breaks in a way that misrepresented the equations.

Answer (score 2):

Some words would be nice. You seem to be counting on the agreement between the third line and the last line, but you don't point that out.  Also, the geometric mean is defined as the positive square root, so you don't need the $\pm$ signs.  I would write it

We are given $b=\sqrt{ac}$

The geometric mean of $a^2$ and $c^2$ is $\sqrt{a^2c^2}=(\sqrt{ac})^2=b^2$

Answer (score 1):

I would write the proof as follows:

If b is the geometric mean of a and c, then $b=\sqrt{ac}$.  Therefore $b^2=ac=\sqrt{a^2c^2}$, so $b^2$ is the geometric mean of $a^2$ and $c^2$.

Note that the converse is not necessarily true. If $b^2=\sqrt{a^2c^2}$, b could be negative, or a or c could be negative, in which case b would not be the geometric mean of a and c.